# 3-in 1 Methods C# Console Applcation

Tags: c#, merge, console

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Combine
{
    class Program 
    { 
        public void marks()
        {
            int marks;
            string Grade = null; // The initial value of grade is 0.

            //Prompt User

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your mark here");
            marks = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (marks < 0 || marks > 100)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("mark entered is not valid");
            }
            else
            {
                if (marks >= 85 && marks <= 100)
                {
                    Grade = "A";
                }
                else if (marks >= 70 && marks <= 84)
                {
                    Grade = "B";
                }
                else if (marks >= 60 && marks <= 69)
                {
                    Grade = "C";
                }
                else if (marks >= 50 && marks <= 59)
                {
                    Grade = "D";
                }
                else if (marks >= 0 && marks <= 49)
                {
                    Grade = "F";
                }

                Console.WriteLine("grade is a " + Grade + " grade");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // INTRO TO APP //
            string b;
            string bselect;
            Program p = new Program();
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome");
            Console.WriteLine("Please Select A Menu Item");
            bselect = Console.ReadLine();
            b = bselect;
            if (bselect == b )
                Console.WriteLine("B - Body Mass Index")
        }
        {
            Console.WriteLine("L - Letter Grade");
            string lselect;
            string l;
            Program p = new Program();

            lselect = Console.ReadLine();
            l = lselect;
            p.marks();

        }
        {
            string t;
            Console.WriteLine("T - Tax Due");
            t = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        {
            string x;
            Console.WriteLine("X - Exit");
            x = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
}
```

For this I am trying to combine three console applications into one with a simple menu option in choosing which app to run. I know I'm supposed to use methods but I am unsure how to correctly do them. I've googled but none of the information I can really understand. Thanks.

Comment: What's with all the extra parenthesis?

Comment: Can you identify the 3 functions that should be run? from the code you post, the compiler won't compile and doesn't seemed to be logical...

Comment: Im just wanting to know how to merge three applications into one by using a main menu option interface .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I understand what you're asking. Based on the code sample you gave, you might have quite a few basics to learn. I hope this gets you moving again...

```
namespace Combine
{
    using System;

    public class LetterGradeProgram
    {
        public void Execute()
        {
            int marks;
            string grade = null;

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your mark here");
            marks = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (marks < 0 || marks > 100)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("mark entered is not valid");
            }
            else
            {
                if (marks >= 85 && marks <= 100)
                {
                    grade = "A";
                }
                else if (marks >= 70 && marks <= 84)
                {
                    grade = "B";
                }
                else if (marks >= 60 && marks <= 69)
                {
                    grade = "C";
                }
                else if (marks >= 50 && marks <= 59)
                {
                    grade = "D";
                }
                else if (marks >= 0 && marks <= 49)
                {
                    grade = "F";
                }

                Console.WriteLine("grade is a " + grade + " grade");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class BodyMassIndexProgram
    {
        public void Execute()
        {
            // do something here
        }
    }

    public class TaxDueProgram
    {
        public void Execute()
        {
            // do something here
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome");
            Console.WriteLine("Please Select A Menu Item");
            Console.WriteLine("B - Body Mass Index");
            Console.WriteLine("T - Tax Due");
            Console.WriteLine("L - Letter Grade");

            string selected = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (selected.ToUpperInvariant())
            {
                case "B":
                    BodyMassIndexProgram bodyMassIndex = new BodyMassIndexProgram();
                    bodyMassIndex.Execute();
                    break;
                case "T":
                    TaxDueProgram taxDue = new TaxDueProgram();
                    taxDue.Execute();
                    break;
                case "L":
                    LetterGradeProgram letterGrade = new LetterGradeProgram();
                    letterGrade.Execute();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Unknown option {0}", selected);
                    break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Bye");
        }
    }
}
```